# Pandas Dataframe: Can I normalize to return percentage for each column using df.apply(pd.value_counts)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have spent the best part of the day searching for this, but cannot find a satisfactory answer.

I want to return the percentage of a categorical dataframe (0 & 1) by column and normalize it to return percentages which I would like to then present as a stacked bar graph.

If applying `value_counts` by `pd.Series.value_counts()`, I could do it by individual columns but that will be time consuming. When I try to use `df.apply(pd.value_counts(normalize=True))`, the following error occurs:

```
'value_counts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'
```

Why can't I apply the same series logic to the whole dataframe using `df.apply`?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `lambda`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x, normalize=True))
```

Comment: Awesome. You answered my question in a minute when I spent the last 6 or 7 hours trying to find that!!